# unable to create a table in magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm trying to create a table using install schema but it throws the error given below
Installing schema... SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `magento`.`questionanswer` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"), query was: CREATE
 TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `questionanswer` (
  `question_id` int NULL COMMENT 'Question ID' ,
  `answer_id` int NULL COMMENT 'Answer ID' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`question_id`, `answer_id`),
  INDEX `QUESTIONANSWER_ANSWER_ID` (`answer_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `QUESTIONANSWER_QUESTION_ID_FAQQUESTION_QUESTION_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `faqquestion` (`question_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `QUESTIONANSWER_ANSWER_ID_FAQANSWER_ANSWER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`answer_id`) REFERENCES `faqanswer` (`answer_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) COMMENT=' Question to answer Linkage Table' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci.

My code from installschema for tables are

```
        //      Creating Question table
    $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
        $installer->getTable('faqquestion')
    )->addColumn(
        'question_id',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
        null,
        ['nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
        'Question ID'
    )->addColumn(
        'question',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        '2M',
        ['nullable' => true,'default' => null],
        'Question'
    )->addColumn(
        'question_identifier',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        255,
        ['nullable' => true],
        'Identifier'
    )->addColumn(
        'question_topic',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        255,
        ['nullable' => true],
        'Topic'
    )->addColumn(
        'question_sortorder',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        1,
        ['nullable' => false,'default' => 0],
        'SortOrder'
    )->addColumn(
        'question_status',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        1,
        ['nullable' => false,'default' => 0],
        'Question Status'
    )->addColumn(
        'question_visibility',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        1,
        ['nullable' => false,'default' => 0],
        'Question Visibility'
    )->addColumn(
        'question_tags',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        255,
        ['nullable' => true],
        'Tags'
    )->setComment(
        'Question Table'
    );
    $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);



    //creating answer table
    $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
        $installer->getTable('faqanswer')
    )->addColumn(
        'answer_id',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
        null,
        ['nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
        'Answer ID'
    )->addColumn(
        'answer',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        '2M',
        ['nullable' => true,'default' => null],
        'Answer'
    )->addColumn(
        'answer_likes',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        1,
        ['nullable' => false,'default' => 0],
        'Likes'
    )->addColumn(
        'answer_dislikes',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        1,
        ['nullable' => false,'default' => 0],
        'Dislikes'
    )->addColumn(
        'answer_author',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        255,
        ['nullable' => true],
        'Author'
    )->addColumn(
        'answer_status',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        1,
        ['nullable' => false,'default' => 0],
        'Answer Status'
    )->setComment(
        'Answer table'
    );
    $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

//        queston and related answer table
    $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
        $installer->getTable('questionanswer')
    )->addColumn(
        'question_id',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        null,
        ['nullable' => true, 'primary' => true],
        'Question ID'
    )->addColumn(
        'answer_id',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        null,
        ['nullable' => true, 'primary' => true],
        'Answer ID'
    )->addIndex(
        $installer->getIdxName('questionanswer', ['answer_id']),
        ['answer_id']
    )->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName('questionanswer', 'question_id', 'faqquestion', 'question_id'),
        'question_id',
        $installer->getTable('faqquestion'),
        'question_id',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE
    )->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName('questionanswer', 'answer_id', 'faqanswer', 'answer_id'),
        'answer_id',
        $installer->getTable('faqanswer'),
        'answer_id',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE
    )->setComment(
        ' Question to aNswer Linkage Table'
    );
    $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because column types are not matching. As I see 
question_id and answer_id have **TYPE_SMALLINT** in reference tables but in questionanswer you created **TYPE_INTEGER** instead of that. So to fix this issue, just need to change **TYPE_INTEGER** to **TYPE_SMALLINT**, questionanswer will be like this:

```
$table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
            $installer->getTable('questionanswer')
        )->addColumn(
            'question_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
            null,
            ['nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'Question ID'
        )->addColumn(
            'answer_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
            null,
            ['nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'Answer ID'
        )->addIndex(
            $installer->getIdxName('questionanswer', ['answer_id']),
            ['answer_id']
        )->addForeignKey(
            $installer->getFkName('questionanswer', 'question_id', 'faqquestion', 'question_id'),
            'question_id',
            $installer->getTable('faqquestion'),
            'question_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE
        )->addForeignKey(
            $installer->getFkName('questionanswer', 'answer_id', 'faqanswer', 'answer_id'),
            'answer_id',
            $installer->getTable('faqanswer'),
            'answer_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE
        )->setComment(
            ' Question to aNswer Linkage Table'
        );
```

This will solve your issue

Regards